# How to create an SMS Intent with multiple recipients?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sony-xperia

I've created an SMS Intent, to compose a message to multiple recipients.

```
String recipients = "smsto:1111;2222;3333"
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(recipients));
intent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
intent.putExtra("compose_mode", true);
```

The problem is, not all devices/apps seem to use semicolon(;) as the recipient separator.

For example, on Sony Experia Z1/Z2, the recipients are separated with a comma(,).
When the Intent is launched on those devices, all the numbers in my Uri is merged to just one recipient. As a result, the message is only sent to the first number (1111).

Is there a better way of adding multiple recipients to this Intent?

Comment: You could lopp through an array of the strings creating a new intent for each one using a for loop

Comment: Thanks Omer, but this will launch the composer multiple times. What if there is 20 recipient? I can not expect my users to press send separately for each one.

Comment: I thought you were sending the messages without any user - interaction